# Dijsktra algorithm - precedessors

Tags: graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am trying to find out what are the predecessors to each vertex in this graph:
[image]

Is the predecessor to the vertex B vertex A or vertex E? The starting vertex is A.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your starting node. If it's A, then predecessor should be A and if it's E then it should be E.

Comment: The starting vertex is A. So the predecessor to B is A, the predecessor to E is A and predecessor to C is B.  To F is E, to G is B, to H is D, to D is C. Am I correct? Thanks!